# Custom-user-federation does not add to keycloak admin panel

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, keycloak, java-11

I have implemented my user-storage-provider like this:

```
public class UserStorageProvider implements org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider, UserLookupProvider, CredentialInputValidator {

    public UserStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public UserStorageProvider(KeycloakSession session, ComponentModel model) {
        this.session = session;
        this.model = model;
    }

    protected KeycloakSession session;
    protected ComponentModel model;

    @Override
    public boolean isConfiguredFor(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, String credentialType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsCredentialType(String credentialType) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RealmModel realm, UserModel user, CredentialInput input) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public UserModel getUserByUsername(String username, RealmModel realm) {
        //here to fetch user from my DB.
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserModel getUserById(String id, RealmModel realm) {
        StorageId storageId = new StorageId(id);
        String username = storageId.getExternalId();
        return getUserByUsername(username, realm);
    }

    @Override
    public UserModel getUserByEmail(String email, RealmModel realm) {
        return null;
    }

    public void close() {

    }
}
```

and its factory class:

```
public class UserStorageProviderFactory implements org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory<UserStorageProvider> {

    public static final String PROVIDER_NAME = "user-provider";


    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "JPA Example User Storage Provider";
    }

    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public UserStorageProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession) {
        return new UserStorageProvider(keycloakSession);
    }

    @Override
    public UserStorageProvider create(KeycloakSession keycloakSession, ComponentModel componentModel) {

        UserStorageProvider provider = new UserStorageProvider(keycloakSession, componentModel);
        provider.session = keycloakSession;
        provider.model = componentModel;
        return provider;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {

    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

and the `org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory` file is located on `META-INF/services/` and the its content is:

com.kian.neshan.userfederation.UserStorageProviderFactory

So I make the jar by `mvn clean package` and put it in deplyment folder of keycloak but when I go to admin panel, my provider is not added to user-federation option

Where is wrong?

Comment: Is there any logs about deployment initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole of my module is correct.

The problem is the **local-keycloak-docker-image** shuold be removed after any changes of the module

Keycloak is started by docker-compose and its images is built by Dockerfile, so after any changes of my module, the local-keycloak-image should be removed by `sudo docker rmi [local-image-name]` to rebuild the image to get the newest my jar file and put it to deployment folder of local-docker-image.